# Can't connect device to Fiware Sigfox IoTAgent

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I am trying to send messages from a device that uses Sigfox to the Fiware system and I am having some troubles.
I see in the sigfox backend that the sigfox cloud receives the messages but when the callback is executed I get and error.

In the sigfox cloud it says:

> Error 404 - Not found

And in the log of the server:

> No context element found

The callback I use is this:

```
Get http://IP:17428/update?id=sigfoxtest&data={data}
```

I can see that the device exists on the system. Also I have tried creating different devices and sending the information with different urls but I always get the same error.

Thanks.

Comment: you should use Post http://IP:17428/update?id=sigfoxtest&data={data}